# Conditional require in express?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, production-environment

I'm using the [reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload) package in development.

It's saved under `devDependancies` in `package.json`.

In my `app.js` I have:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    reload(server, app)
}
```

Heroku strips out all packages under `devDependancies` after building, and my `import reload from 'reload'` is throwing an error. I'm using `babel` to build it in production btw.

**Heroku logs:**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'reload'
2018-05-16T01:00:46.213772+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
2018-05-16T01:00:46.213773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
2018-05-16T01:00:46.213776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
```

I'm aware I can [skip the "pruning" part](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning), but would prefer to strip loading of `reload` module in production instead.

How do I conditionally import or require a package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general rule is to put your import at the top, but you don't have to

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('reload')(server, app)
}
```

should work.

Comment: There are a "performance lost"  when using conditional `require` instead at the top?  I am using `const x= require('x')` with both modes.